# 'f' character is considered as true in a ng-show

Tags: angularjs

When using angular, I had a very strange issue:

```
<div ng-app>
    <textarea ng-model="resp" placeholder="Response"></textarea>
    <a ng-show="resp">Respond</a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgtYL/)

When writing something into the textarea, the Respond link is shown.

However, strangely, when writing the letter **'f'**, the Respond button doesn't show.

A workaround for this is to use the condition `resp.length>0`, but I wonder why the letter 'f' behaves in a special way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually 'f' is considered as `false`.

AngularJS uses the `toBoolean` function internally to evaluate `ng-show` / `ng-hide` expressions.

You should get the same behaviour for "f", "false", "0", "n", "no" and "[]".

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1229.

This is angular's `toBoolean` function:

```
function toBoolean(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    value = true;
  } else if (value && value.length !== 0) {
    var v = lowercase("" + value);
    value = !(v == 'f' || v == '0' || v == 'false' || v == 'no' || v == 'n' || v == '[]');
  } else {
    value = false;
  }
  return value;
}
```

### Update:

In AngularJS 1.3+ this behaviour has been removed.

Quote: Due to [bdfc9c02](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bdfc9c02d021e08babfbc966a007c71b4946d69d), values 'f', '0', 'false', 'no', 'n', '[]' are no longer treated as falsy. The only JavaScript values that are treated as falsy by the expression parser are now: false, null, undefined, NaN, 0 and "".

Comment: +1 This is correct. Suggested workaround is to use explicit checks like `myString.length > 0` or `myBool === true` in your expressions.

Comment: it's quite odd to esteem 'f' as false in javascript is true so I don't really know the point. Could anyone explain me the matter, please ?

Comment: @Whisher I guess that's just how the angular team decided to implement this function so as to allow some shorthand "falsy" values. This behaviour may be removed in the future as noted here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3436.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to check to see if resp is an empty string. Since your textarea is a string value if the string is not empty then your respond text will be displayed.

```
<div ng-app>
    <textarea ng-model="resp" placeholder="Response"></textarea>
    <a ng-show="resp != ''">Respond</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's correct, but my question was not what workarounds they are, but rather what is the explanation off the phenomenon

Answer (score 0):

It's just the opposite, `"f"` is treated as `false`. Note that so are all the following:

```
"F"
"false"
"FALSE"
"FaLsE"
"  faLse "
""
" "
"   "
```

(i.e., case and leading/trailing whitespace do not matter)

However, partial words (e.g., `"fa", "fal", "fals"`) are not.

Comment: "parsed" is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: @blesh a little nit-picky, but fine, I edited. I'm not really in the mood to argue it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out using strict checks for conditions.  'F', 'f', 'N', 'n', '0' also don't work in your fiddle.  They are considered to be shortcuts for 'false'.  Typing out 'false' also fails to show the 'Respond' button.